# simple lldb error when getting text via uitextfield

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to receive an username through an uitextfield on the start-up xib. I've connected it to this action:

```
- (IBAction)nickEntered:(UITextField *)sender{

   .....
}
```

I'm using Did End on Exit as the trigger. It loads the username screen, however even when the nickEntered method is empty, when i press enter/go button of the simulator, it gives a simple green error which says 'lldb' in debugger inside nickEntered method and nothing else. I don't know how to debug it further using the tools. Thanks for any help.

Comment: does the console show anything? do you have ANY breakpoints? What's the signal causing it

Comment: It only says lldb on console. breakpoint is always inside nickEntered even when there's no line in it. I don't know about the signal.

Comment: do you have any breakpoints active (editor doesnt show it). Check in xcode's breakpoints inspector -- CMD+7